# Check box function using siblings().map(function() needs to convert to php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am trying to pass one td of data to php through an ajax call when checkbox is checked ( or multiple checkboxes are checked). I have a dynamic table with the first td containing the checkbox and the second td containing the row id.. All i need is the row id for each row that has a checkbox checked.. i can get all of the rows td with this js code

```
 arr=[];
  //If all selected value has to pass through ajax one by one row/
  $('input:checked').parent().each(function(){

   arr.push($(this).siblings().map(function(){
   return $(this).text()
   }).get());

});

$.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: ({StatusEnterUpdate:$('#StatusEnterUpdate').val(), TrackingUpdate: $('#TrackingUpdate').val(),
                        ShipDateUpdate: $('#ShipDateUpdate').val(), LocationUpdate: $('#ShipLocation5').val(), QBEnterUpdate: $('#QBEnterUpdate').val(),
                        IDArray:arr,                        
                        }),
```

but the passed value for IDarray is as follows with var_dump in the php file

```
array(31) {
 [1]=>
 array(18) {
   [0]=>
    string(4) "7231"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "14566"
 }
  [2]=>
  array(18) {
[0]=>
 string(4) "7232"
[1]=>
    string(8) "14566"
}
```

I only need values of array(18) [0]=> string(4) (could be up to 200 values)
i know i am missing something or there is an easier way to just get the td containing that data instead of the entire row of data. i tried

```
json_decode($_POST["IDArray"],true);
```

even though i knew it would not work and of course it did not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to access the first value of each array element of IDArray, which you can do through a foreach loop e.g.

```
foreach ($_POST['IDArray'] as $IDArray) {
    $id = $IDArray[0];
    // do something with $id
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly thanks i knew i just missed something